# Dependency injection with @protocol?

Tags: objective-c, interface, protocols

Can I use a `@protocol` for interfacing between classes? My main goal is to do some dependency injection like in Java (with interfaces and implements).

I've got the following classes: `SignUpServiceImpl` (which has an interface called `SignUpService`) and `ServiceHelperImpl` (interface is `ServiceHelper`).

I don't want to hard wire both implementations together so I use a `@protocol` in `ServiceHelper` which is implemented by `ServiceHelperImpl`. Then `SignUpServiceImpl` is initialized with `ServiceHelper` like this:

```
- (id)initWithHelper:(ServiceHelper *)myServiceHelper
```

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible? It looks so much easier in Java....

Comment: I've no idea what you're trying to accomplish ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An objc protocol is very similar to a Java interface.

The blocking point for you may be how you expect things are actually tied together -- or protocol syntax.

Declare a protocol:

```
@protocol ServiceHelperProtocol
- (void)help;
@end
```

Use it in a class:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
- (id)initWithServiceHelper:(id<ServiceHelperProtocol>)inServiceHelper;
@end

@implementation SomeClass

- (id)initWithServiceHelper:(id<ServiceHelperProtocol>)inServiceHelper
{
  self = [super init];
  if (nil != self) {
    [inServiceHelper help];
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

`MONHelper` adopts the protocol:

```
@interface MONHelper : NSObject < ServiceHelperProtocol > 
...
@end

@implementation MONHelper
- (void)help { NSLog(@"helping..."); }
@end
```

In use:

```
MONHelper * helper = [MONHelper new];
SomeClass * someClass = [[SomeClass alloc] initWithServiceHelper:helper];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

To accept an object that conforms to a protocol, your init method should be like this:

```
- (id)initWithHelper:(id<ServiceHelper>)myServiceHelper
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep a number of different implementations behind a unified class interface, one way to do this in Objective-C is to create an abstract class `SignUpService`, then in the `init` method of `SignUpService`, instead of returning self you actually return a instance of the class that you want to implement it, so in your case, `SignUpServiceImpl`.

This is how certain class clusters in Cocoa like NSString work.

Let me know if you need more info.